# Floating parent div grows to hypothetical width of floating child div

Tags: css, css-float

I have a parent element that floats and a child element that also floats, plus some content to give the child element some dimensions, as follows:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    WWWWWWW WWWWWWW WWWWWWW
  </div>
</div>
```

The child has its width restricted through `width` and `min-width`:

```
#parent {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

#child {
  width: 16%;
  min-width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
```

What I would expect to happen is that the parent div has the same width as the child div, and not 100%, since it's floated.

What happens though is neither. The parent div has some width inbetween. What seems to happen is that the parent div has the width that the child div *would* have if it wasn't width-restricted, i.e. the width that the child would get from the text in it stretching over just one line instead of wrapping.

However the child is set to be narrower so why does the parent not shrink to that too?
And how can I get it to do that?

See a full example on http://jsbin.com/wipafizocu/edit?html,css,output that uses some colouring to show the divs. You should see that the black parent box does not extend to the full width of the grey background but is also wider than the red child box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-width-property):

> If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.2.

There's a circular dependency between the parent and child widths. As the parent has `width: auto`, its width is calculated based on the shrink-to-fit algorithm described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#float-width), resulting in the behavior you observe, namely,

> the parent div has the width that the child div would have if it wasn't width-restricted, i.e. the width that the child would get from the text in it stretching over just one line instead of wrapping.

The child's width is then calculated as a percentage of the used width of the parent. If the parent were to shrink again to fit the child, then the child would no longer be 16% of the parent width, and its width would have to be recalculated. You can see where this is going.

So implementations agree not to calculate the width of either element more than once. Note that specifying a min-width does not influence any of this behavior.

There isn't much of a solution here; not even flexbox will help, since you're relying on undefined behavior. You may have to rethink your layout.